# Pandas: join with outer product

Tags: python, pandas

I want to multiply a lookup table (`demand`), given for multiple commodities (here: Water, Elec) and area types (Com, Ind, Res) with a DataFrame (`areas`) that is a table of areas for these area types.

```
import pandas as pd
areas = pd.DataFrame({'Com':[1,2,3], 'Ind':[4,5,6]})
demand = pd.DataFrame({'Water':[4,3], 
                       'Elec':[8,9]}, index=['Com', 'Ind'])
```

Before:

```
areas
   Com  Ind
0    1    4
1    2    5
2    3    6

demand
     Elec  Water
Com     8      4
Ind     9      3
```

After:

```
area_demands                  
     Com          Ind         
     Elec  Water  Elec  Water 
0       8      4    36     12 
1      16      8    45     15 
2      24     12    54     18
```

**My attempt**

Verbose and incomplete; does not work for arbitrary number of commodities.

```
areas = pd.DataFrame({'area': areas.stack()})
areas.index.names = ['Edge', 'Type']
both = areas.reset_index(1).join(demand, on='Type')
both['Elec'] = both['Elec'] * both['area']
both['Water'] = both['Water'] * both['area']
del both['area']
# almost there; it must be late, I fail to make 'Type' a hierarchical column...
```

Almost there:

```
     Type  Elec  Water
Edge
0     Com     8      4
0     Ind    36     12
1     Com    16      8
1     Ind    45     15
2     Com    24     12
2     Ind    54     18
```

**In short**

How to join/multiply the DataFrames `areas` and `demand` together in a decent way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
areas = pd.DataFrame({'Com':[1,2,3], 'Ind':[4,5,6]})
demand = pd.DataFrame({'Water':[4,3], 
                       'Elec':[8,9]}, index=['Com', 'Ind'])

def multiply_by_demand(series):
    return demand.ix[series.name].apply(lambda x: x*series).stack()
df = areas.apply(multiply_by_demand).unstack(0)
print(df)
```

yields

```
    Com          Ind       
   Elec  Water  Elec  Water
0     8      4    36     12
1    16      8    45     15
2    24     12    54     18
```

---

**How this works:**

First, look at what happens when we call `areas.apply(foo)`. `foo` gets passed the columns of `areas` one-by-one:

```
def foo(series):
    print(series)

In [226]: areas.apply(foo)
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: Com, dtype: int64
0    4
1    5
2    6
Name: Ind, dtype: int64
```

So suppose `series` is one such column:

```
In [230]: series = areas['Com']

In [231]: series
Out[231]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: Com, dtype: int64
```

We can muliply demand by this series this way:

```
In [229]: demand.ix['Com'].apply(lambda x: x*series)
Out[229]: 
       0   1   2
Elec   8  16  24
Water  4   8  12
```

This has half the numbers we want, but not in the form we want them.
Now `apply` needs to return a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`. One way to turn a `DataFrame` into a `Series` is to use `stack`. Look at what happens if we
`stack` this DataFrame. The columns become a new level of the index:

```
In [232]: demand.ix['Com'].apply(lambda x: x*areas['Com']).stack()
Out[232]: 
Elec   0     8
       1    16
       2    24
Water  0     4
       1     8
       2    12
dtype: int64
```

So, using this as the return value of `multiply_by_demand`, we get:

```
In [235]: areas.apply(multiply_by_demand)
Out[235]: 
         Com  Ind
Elec  0    8   36
      1   16   45
      2   24   54
Water 0    4   12
      1    8   15
      2   12   18
```

Now we want the first level of the index to become columns. This can be done with `unstack`:

```
In [236]: areas.apply(multiply_by_demand).unstack(0)
Out[236]: 
    Com          Ind       
   Elec  Water  Elec  Water
0     8      4    36     12
1    16      8    45     15
2    24     12    54     18
```

---

Per the request in the comments, here is the `pivot_table` solution:

```
import pandas as pd
areas = pd.DataFrame({'Com':[1,2,3], 'Ind':[4,5,6]})
demand = pd.DataFrame({'Water':[4,3], 
                       'Elec':[8,9]}, index=['Com', 'Ind'])

areas = pd.DataFrame({'area': areas.stack()})
areas.index.names = ['Edge', 'Type']
both = areas.reset_index(1).join(demand, on='Type')
both['Elec'] = both['Elec'] * both['area']
both['Water'] = both['Water'] * both['area']
both.reset_index(inplace=True)
both = both.pivot_table(values=['Elec', 'Water'], rows='Edge', cols='Type')
both = both.reorder_levels([1,0], axis=1)
both = both.reindex(columns=both.columns[[0,2,1,3]])
print(both)
```

Comment: I think using pivot_table means you don't need to delete area (and I think is nicer to read) `both.pivot_table(values=['Elec', 'Water'], rows='Edge', cols='Type')`

Comment: `del` + `pivot` turns out to be faster than `pivot_table` in this case. Maybe the reason `pivot` exists is because it is faster than `pivot_table` for those cases where it is applicable (such as when you don't need  aggregation).

Comment: Wow, awesome walkthrough! `apply` is now among my top 5 functions to always remember. Concerning the `pivot_table` solution: At which point  am I supposed to enter the line? No matter when in my attempt above, I always get `no item named Edge`.