# Pandas: outer product of row and col sums

Tags: python, r, pandas, outer-join, chi-squared

In Pandas, I am trying to manually code a chi-square test. I am comparing `row 0` with `row 1` in the dataframe below.

```
data
       2      3      5      10     30
0      3      0      6      5      0
1  33324  15833  58305  54402  38920
```

For this, I need to calculate the expected cell counts for each cell as: `cell(i,j) = rowSum(i)*colSum(j) / sumAll`. In R, I can do this simply by taking the `outer()` products:

```
Exp_counts <- outer(rowSums(data), colSums(data), "*")/sum(data)    # Expected cell counts
```

I used numpy's outer product function to imitate the outcome of the above R code:

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.outer(data.sum(axis=1),data.sum(axis=0))/ (data.sum().sum()), index=data.index, columns=data.columns.values)
       2      3      5      10     30
0      2      1      4      3      2
1  33324  15831  58306  54403  38917
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a Pandas function?

Comment: would this not work? 
`not_yet_df = np.outer(data.sum(axis=0), data.sum(axis=1))/ (data.sum().sum())` and then `now_a_df = pd.DataFrame(not_yet_df)`
besides, you can call the `outer` function from pandas without importing numpy if you want with `pd.np.outer(..)`

Comment: Yes, it does (but I realised the axes order need to be inverted while summing). I re-worded my question, including the numpy solution. I am looking for a way to do this with a Pandas function.

Comment: why do you need a pandas function anyway?

Comment: I feel like Pandas is probably able to do this. I want to learn.

Comment: I think this SO answers your question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578686/pandas-join-with-outer-product

Answer (score 1):

A Complete solution using only Pandas built-in methods:

```
def outer_product(row):
    numerator = df.sum(1).mul(row.sum(0))
    denominator = df.sum(0).sum(0)
    return (numerator.floordiv(denominator))

df.apply(outer_product)
```

[image]

Timings: For 1 million rows of DF.

[image]